# Visual studio statement is not valid in a namespace

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I'm using visual studio and it keeps saying "statement is not valid in a namespace".
I don't know what to do:

```
Private Sub Timer_hip_walk_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer_hip_walk.Tick
```

Comment: Is your project type an EXE or web page?

Comment: You need to post more context for your code.  A `Sub` needs to be in a `Class` or `Module`, but without seeing the rest of the code, we can't tell what the issue is.